# Translating a closed-source Qt/QML application

Tags: string, qt, qml, translation, reverse-engineering

I have a binary of an abandoned, which uses Qt4+QML. The QML files are embedded using qrc. Since the person who would benefit from using the app doesn't speak English, I'd like to translate the app.

The translatable strings are already marked with `qsTr`:

```
 $ strings abplayer | grep qsTr  
                      ? qsTr("Disable auto-play next track")
                      : qsTr("Enable auto-play next track")
                text: qsTr("Now playing");
                text: qsTr("About");
        message: "<small>" + qsTr("Version") + " " + appVersion + "</small><br><br>" +
                 qsTr("A simple audio book player.") + "<br><br>" +
                      qsTr("is empty")
        text: qsTr("indexing")
```

Is there any way I can sideload a translation? The executable is a Linux armel binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. If the application uses a dynamically-linked copy of Qt, you should be able to figure out what exact compiler version it was compiled with, then:

   1. Compile your own copy of binary-compatible Qt 4.
   2. Replace the bundled Qt dlls with yours, and verify that it still works.
   3. Modify your copy of Qt to inject translations in the `QApplication` constructor.
2. You can also literally append new the new translation files to the executable, and patch the existing resource catalog to point to the new resource files.

Comment: How can I do the second approach? Isn't it possible to replace the strings directly in the executable?

Comment: You don't replace them. Append your new translation files to the executable, then find where the resource directory is, and manually patch up offsets into the newly appended files. You also have to patch up the executable's ELF/PE/Mach-O headers so that your appended sections end up mapped into the process's address space. Obviously this is platform-dependent. The process would probably involve dumping the binary to some human-readable form so that you can see its structure, then either using this to patch it, or re-building the binary from the dump.

Comment: Can you please illustrate it with an example? I still don't know how to do it. You can get the application binary here: https://openrepos.net/content/dkalitinkin/abplayer . Besides, I added to the OP that the executable is a Linux ARM binary (maybe this matters)

Comment: You will have to understand the structure of the ELF binary, the tools needed to read it, and figure out how to do it. An "example" would be the entire procedure.